# How to generate one objects from two similar xml documents with jaxb

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm trying to integrate with some provider REST API within xml. I have two requests and two very similar responses: ***Operation*** response and ***Check*** response.

***Operation:***

```
<Response>
<ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode>
 <ReturnMessage>OK</ReturnMessage>
 <Commands>
  <OperationResponseCommand>
   <ResultCode>412</ResultCode>
   <ResultMessage>Some message hear</ResultMessage>
   <OperationId>125206188472552900</OperationId>
   <Id>14507921</Id>
  </OperationResponseCommand>
 </Commands>
</Response>
```

***Check:***

```
<Response>
 <ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode>
 <ReturnMessage>OK</ReturnMessage>
 <Commands>
  <CheckResponseCommand>
   <ResultCode>412</ResultCode>
   <ResultMessage>Some message hear</ResultMessage>
   <OperationId>125206188472552900</OperationId>
  </CheckResponseCommand>
 </Commands>
</Response>
```

As you can see, the differences are:

1. `<OperationResponseCommand>` instead of `<CheckResponseCommand>`
   in first xml.
2. One additional tag `<Id>` inside
   `<OperationResponseCommand>`.

And I have two classes for *Response* and for *Command*.

*First:*

```java
    @Data
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Response")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Response {
    
        @XmlElement(name = "ReturnCode")
        private Integer returnCode;
        @XmlElement(name = "ReturnMessage")
        private String returnMessage;
        
        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Commands")
        @XmlElement(name = "OperationResponseCommand")
        private List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

*Second:*

```java
    @Data
    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Command {
    
        @XmlElement(name = "ResultCode")
        private Integer resultCode;
        @XmlElement(name = "ResultMessage")
        private String resultMessage;
        @XmlElement(name = "OperationId")
        private String operationId;
        @XmlElement(name = "Id")
        private Integer id;
    }
```

For building response object from xml I'm using this class:

```java
    public class JAXBOperations {
    
        public <T> T buildObjectFromXml(Class<T> clazz, String xml) {
    
            try {
    
                StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = createUnmarshaller(clazz);
    
                return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Exception has been occurred while creating unmarshaller to parse xml to object");
            }
        }
    
        public <T> String buildXmlFromObject(T objectToXml) {
    
            try {
    
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                Marshaller marshaller = createMarshaller(objectToXml.getClass());
                marshaller.marshal(objectToXml, writer);
    
                return writer.toString();
    
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Exception has been occurred while creating marshaller to parse object to xml");
            }
        }
    
        private <T> Marshaller createMarshaller(Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException {
    
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
            return jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        }
    
        private <T> Unmarshaller createUnmarshaller(Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException {
    
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
            return jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        }
    }
```

Method *buildObjectFromXml*. And it works fine for first xml response. I have an object like this:

```
Response(
 returnCode=0, returnMessage=OK,  
 commands=[Command( 
  resultCode=417,   
  resultMessage=Processing,  
  operationId=b6619f26-8583-4272-b89d-d1b200109d06,   
  id=157427079)])
```

But for the second xml response it doesn't works. I have:

```
Response(
 returnCode=0, 
 returnMessage=OK, 
 commands=[])
```

I tried to change the code of my *Response* class. Like this:

```java
    @Data
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Response")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class tResponse {
    
        @XmlElement(name = "ReturnCode")
        private Integer returnCode;
        @XmlElement(name = "ReturnMessage")
        private String returnMessage;
        
        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Commands")
        @XmlElementRefs({
            @XmlElementRef(name = "OperationResponseCommand", type = Command.class),
            @XmlElementRef(name = "CheckResponseCommand", type = Command.class)})
        private List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Or this:

```java
    @Data
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Response")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Response {
    
        @XmlElement(name = "ReturnCode")
        private Integer returnCode;
        @XmlElement(name = "ReturnMessage")
        private String returnMessage;
    
        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Commands")
        @XmlElement(name = "OperationResponseCommand")
        private List<Command> operstionCommands = new ArrayList<>();
    
        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Commands")
        @XmlElement(name = "CheckResponseCommand")
        private List<Command> checkCommands = new ArrayList<>()
    }
```

But it both doesn't works too.

My question is: *what I'm doing wrong? How can I change code of my two classes to correct converting to object both types of xml responses?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For representing the XML elements `<OperationResponseCommand>`
and `<CheckResponseCommand>` you will need separate classes
which should be subclasses of your `Command` classes.
Let's call them `OperationResponseCommand` and `CheckResponseCommand`.

The properties common to all commands should remain in your
`Command` class. It is also a good idea to declare this class as abstract.

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class Command {

    @XmlElement(name = "ResultCode")
    private Integer resultCode;

    @XmlElement(name = "ResultMessage")
    private String resultMessage;

    @XmlElement(name = "OperationId")
    private Integer operationId;
}
```

The properties specific for the commands should go into the subclasses:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OperationResponseCommand extends Command {

    @XmlElement(name = "Id")
    private Integer id;
}
```

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CheckResponseCommand extends Command {

}
```

Finally, in your `Response` class you need to enhance the annotations
of your `List<Command> commands` property, so that JAXB
will know which object class needs to be instantiated depending
on the XML element name of the commands.
(See also the [javadoc of `@XmlElements`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElements.html).)

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Commands")
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "OperationResponseCommand", type = OperationResponseCommand.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "CheckResponseCommand", type = CheckResponseCommand.class)
})
private List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();
```